# CSS Override not working properly in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, themes

I just trying to override the css some of my pages but its not working. i have a file override css and i want to override in my AppList page. can anyone resolve my problem.? Thankyou.

i have attached what i am facing the error:

[image]

Here is my sample code:

```
//compStyleOverride.js

 /* @param {JsonObject} theme Plain Json Object */

export function componentStyleOverrides(theme) {
  return {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontWeight: 500,
          textTransform: "capitalize",
          borderRadius: "4px",
        },
      },
    },
    MuiCardHeader: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: theme.colors.textDark,
          padding: "24px",
        },
        title: {
          fontSize: "1.125rem",
        },
      },
    },
}
```

```
//AppList.js

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "../themes/index";
import { componentStyleOverrides } from "../themes/compStyleOverride";

export const AppList = (props) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={componentStyleOverrides}>
      <Card>
        <List {...props} pagination={null} perPage={9999}>
          <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="name" />
            <TextField source="label" />
            <RichTextField source="description" />
            <EditButton />
          </Datagrid>
        </List>
      </Card>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try using `{componentStyleOverrides(theme)}` instead?

Comment: Also please note that your type is wrong. `@param {JsonObject} theme Plain Json Object` is a JS Object, not a JSON object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you mean like this ```theme={componentStyleOverrides(theme)}``` but its also showing same error.

Comment: Please share the definition of `theme`?

Comment: I tried like this```<ThemeProvider theme={componentStyleOverrides(theme)}> <Card>.... </Card></ThemeProvider>```

Comment: That's not what I asked? The error says that `theme.colors` is undefined. Please share what `theme` is

Comment: @evolutionxbox I shared my files here (its just a files not working codeSandbox) please check once - https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-mountain-frii9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Theme is not being imported correctly. `Could not find module in path: './theme' relative to '/src/App.js'` - Also, `theme` is a function? So try `{componentStyleOverrides(theme())}`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox its imported properly now and i tried with this ```{componentStyleOverrides(theme())}``` same error is accure sir.

Comment: The same error? Try debugging it yourself, remove anything that doesn't relate to the problem, and try and figure out why `theme.colors` is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236088/discussion-between-joe-and-evolutionxbox).